# XNA Kinect Color Stream Performance Issues

Tags: xna, performance, kinect

I am developing an XNA game using Kinect. It requires using `Depth` and `Color` streams for extracting only the player's image from the color image. So far I can extract the image and set their data into a `Texture2D` object, but the performance gets very low for the whole game when I do that. I tried setting only black color for player's silhouette and performance gets better but I need to use `Color Stream` with as little performance issues as possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should post your code.